# How does android stack really work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, activity-finish

I have tried exiting an app with multiple activities with the following   code :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
```

In this code by my understanding the first line clears the stack. This means after the execution of the first line there is no activity in front of the app. To check my understanding i added a Toast text to check after both lines of code. But the toast text appeared in the app as well as only the second activity was closed.

I want to understand working of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is by using it when you start activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then what happens is that the second Activity is started after all other activities are destroyed - the stack is cleared.
If you want to close all activites you can use finishAffinity(), but it is only supported from api 16 and above.